# Entity Framework Join Stuck

Tags: entity-framework, join

I want to join Customer and Orders table on northwind database by using entity framework but I'm getting an error on 'DataBind'.

```
    public void CustomerJoin()
    {
        using (var ctx = new northwindContext())
        {
            var found = from mycust in ctx.Customers
                        join cust in ctx.Orders on mycust.CustomerID equals cust.CustomerID
                        select new { Customer = mycust, Order = cust }; ;
            grdEmployees.DataSource = found.ToList();
            grdEmployees.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Error Message of grdEmployees.DataBind();:The data source for GridView with id 'grdEmployees' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content

Comment: Looks like WinForms doesn't like to bind to a List of anomalous typed objects.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing wrong when you are binding

```
grdEmployees.DataSource = found.ToList();
```

You should make a class having properties for all column that you want to show

and iterate through found something like this

```
list<newClassToShow> itemsToBind = new <newClassToShow>();
foreach(var item in found.ToList())
{
   newClassToShow it = new newClassToShow()
it.property1 = item.column1;//do this for all item
itemToBind.add(it);
}
```

now bind the list to gridEmployee

Comment: List<Models.Customer> itemsToBind = new <Models.Customer>(); getting an error here!

Comment: If you are doing this in c# do like this.                      public class newClassToShow
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string address { get; set; }
}                                                                        Make object of this class and assign columns from item as given in answer Note :- class is only sample make property as par your requirement